# u-boot cross compile on cygwin

Tags: cygwin, cross-compiling, u-boot, linaro

I am trying to build u-boot for my arm target on cygwin. I took the latest u-boot (2019.10) I took the latest linaro gnu-eabi toolchain.
The first thing I found - the makefile adds "-ansi" flag to cygwin compilation and it fails and if to remove this flag it is able to compile.
Now I found that my compiler doesn't know where is its libgcc.a. So build fails.
If anybody has experience in cross-compiling u-boot on cygwin - please, I need your advice. How to do it?
Thanks

Comment: git blame teaches that Masahiro Yamada added the -ansi flag. I suggest you take his current email address from git log and ask him with CC to the U-Boot list.

Comment: If your actual goal is to build u-boot under cygwin, I understand. Otherwise, an easier path for building u-boot on windows would be to use [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10), or [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) +  [Ubuntu 18.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/) for example.

Comment: Yes, use of cygwin is my goal. Under WSL there are no problems. So if somebody has relevant experience - please share

Comment: In this case, just be aware that initial, more ten years old, Windows support was intended for mingw32, and that, according to this (recent) [post](https://www.mail-archive.com/u-boot@lists.denx.de/msg344042.html), the code base for the tools may have changed so much that a fair amount of work may be needed in order to achieve your goal. Basically, that means you may well on your own in terms of support on cygwin, and that you may have to port the code by yourself.

Comment: And I would tend to agree with the `I'm guessing more duct tape on the make system And I would be needed to get
MinGW working, and my thought is that ugliness isn't worth the benefit
anymore.` statement from the post referenced  above.